# iphone GData spreadsheet unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, spreadsheet, gdata

I've used the GData spreadsheets code for MAC to write a corresponding iPhone version (the same code), but I get a exception thrown:
[GDataEntryBase worksheetsFeedURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
It appears to me that when fetching the entries from the spreadsheet feed, I got a array of GDataEntryBase (iPhone version) instead of GDataEntrySpreadsheet.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the method is worksheetsFeedURL:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base class is created when the needed subclasses aren't compiled and linked into the application.

Be sure the -ObjC linker flag is set for your project, and that `-DGDATA_REQUIRE_SERVICE_INCLUDES=1` and `-DGDATA_INCLUDE_SPREADSHEET_SERVICE=1` are defined for the target that includes the spreadsheet classes. ( in `GData.xcodeproj > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags` )

These are discussed on the [BuildingTheLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary) wiki page for the project.

Comment: I have set the -ObjC flag in the project's linker build settings and the two defines in the project's target build settings (Other C flags), but the exception is still there. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting this error: Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleSpreadsheet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SpreadSheetManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6. I think the Spreadsheets aren't compiled into the static library somehow. Please help, any help is appreciated! Thanks allot!

Comment: Fixed the compilation error, your information was helpful. Many thanks!!

Comment: I think I solved it! The GDataEntrySpreadsheet.h and GDataEntrySpreadsheet.m where not compiled into the static library, so I added them manually into Build Phases. Someone should tell Google about that!